# Create a listview With Multiple Objects in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I want to create a listview that displays many different things on Android Studio. The purpose of this is to create a dynamic form that will have any number of category A, B, or C according to what the form maker wants.

So, the form maker will get a list of options: Category A, B, C etc. and they choose how many spots for each they want. For example, let's say A is "References" and the form maker wants to have three spots for it, I want that the form to have 3 spots for category A.

Long story short, how would is there an array adapter or something that would help me with this? Is there a tutorial you guys know about?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is to create a custom Adapter, and in that adapter create a collection of type Object (or any superclass common to those classes). Then, in the `getView` method, depending on the type of object you are retrieving from the collection, display one thing or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Adapter, there are lot of tutorials online.Best ones are 
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Also I would suggest you to look into recyclerview which is faster.

http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example

Here's how a customlistadapter would look like:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<obj> item) {
        //set any data you want
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return item.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);


        return convertView;
    }

}
```